# Fotorama zoom_in and zoom_out buttons are not working in Magento 2.3.6

Tags: magento2, product-images, gallery, zoom, fotorama

The zoom_in and zoom_out buttons are not working in the product pop-up gallery, however, while clicking the image, the image gets zoomed on the first double click and gets zoomed out on the second double click.
any suggestion for the solution?
[image: 2]

Comment: Did you ever come up with a cause? I've been seeing this happen intermittently between different themes.

Comment: @Eirik, for me it was because the values were not fetched in the gallery.phtml from view.xml. I have provided the values in json in gallery.phtml and it worked.

Comment: @ReshadZazai I am facing the same problem, Can you share the gallery.phtml file code?

Comment: @ReshadZazai Brother! please guide me on this, how you fixed this problem?

Comment: @FaisalSheikh I have passed the options in json for 
"magnifierOpts": {
                "enabled": true,
                "fullscreenzoom":20,
                "mode": "outside",
                "eventType": "hover"
                },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Product media data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
 */
?>

<?php
$images = $block->getGalleryImages()->getItems();
$mainImage = current(array_filter($images, function ($img) use ($block) {
    return $block->isMainImage($img);
}));

if (!empty($images) && empty($mainImage)) {
    $mainImage = $block->getGalleryImages()->getFirstItem();
}

$helper = $block->getData('imageHelper');
$mainImageData = $mainImage ?
    $mainImage->getData('medium_image_url') :
    $helper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');

?>

<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <img
        alt="main product photo"
        class="gallery-placeholder__image"
        src="<?= /* @noEscape */ $mainImageData ?>"
    />
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": {
                "enabled": true,
                "fullscreenzoom":20,
                "mode": "outside",
                "eventType": "hover"
                },
                "data": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                 "breakpoints": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you brother, I am going to try this...

Comment: Thank you so much brother! after applying you solution, Zoom functionality is working fine now.

Comment: I also posted a question here on stackexchange: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/338064/magento-2-4-1-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-button-is-not-working-inside-product-popup-i  if you want then you can give same answer there also

Comment: @FaisalSheikh glad it helped.