# Magento 2.4.1: Zoom_in and Zoom_out button is not working inside product popup image on product details page

Tags: product-images, magento2.4.1, gallery-image, fotorama

I am facing issue with image zoom_in and zoom_out functionality inside product image popup on product details page, I am also including screenshot for better under standing

[image]

Please help and how can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 * Product media data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
 */
?>

<?php
$images = $block->getGalleryImages()->getItems();
$mainImage = current(array_filter($images, function ($img) use ($block) {
    return $block->isMainImage($img);
}));

if (!empty($images) && empty($mainImage)) {
    $mainImage = $block->getGalleryImages()->getFirstItem();
}

$helper = $block->getData('imageHelper');
$mainImageData = $mainImage ?
    $mainImage->getData('medium_image_url') :
    $helper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');

?>

<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <img
        alt="main product photo"
        class="gallery-placeholder__image"
        src="<?= /* @noEscape */ $mainImageData ?>"
    />
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": {
                "enabled": true,
                "fullscreenzoom":20,
                "mode": "outside",
                "eventType": "hover"
                },
                "data": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                 "breakpoints": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks brother, it's worked.